# Pydev 7.2.1 not showing on Eclipse 4.12 on Mac Mojave

Tags: mac, python, eclipse

I have followed the previous answers to this question with no resolution.

I have tried both marketplace and zip file load into plugins.

Mac Version

```
Mojave v 10.14.5
```

Eclipse is installed in my home directory.

```
~/eclipse/cpp-2019-06
```

I have tried the -clean option.

```
open ./Eclipse.app --args -clean
```

It does not appear to do anything at least it does not have the pydev show up in perspective.

```
java --version
java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The about eclipse install shows pydev as installed.
No pydev perspective is seen. Opening test.py file in eclipse says there are better support in Marketplace and that the file is being opened in an outside editor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this worked. But it did so hopefully it saves someone hours debugging it.

```
Deleted the CPP install of Eclipse.
Installed the Java Version of Eclipse.
From Market place added the CPP package.
Restarted Eclipse
From Market place added pydev package
Restarted Eclipse
Now the pydev shows up in window->perspective->other->pydev.
```